# NoClassDefFoundError on ProfilerRuntimeObjLiveliness error when profiling on WildFly in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, wildfly, profiler

I am trying to profile a web application running on WildFly (8.2.0.Final "Tweek" version) in Netbeans 8.0.2. I keep getting a NoClassDefFoundError on ProfilerRuntimeObjLiveliness. I tried adding "org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server" to JAVA_OPTS in standalone.conf.bat, but that didn't change anything. The app deploys fine when I'm not trying to profile it.
I've tried jdk7 and 8 (both 64 bit)

```
Calling "D:\WildFlyTC-8585\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
"JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server -server -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost,127.0.0.1,ComputerName -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -agentpath:D:\NetBeans8.0.2\profiler\lib\deployed\jdk16\windows-amd64\profilerinterface.dll=D:\NetBeans8.0.2\profiler\lib,5140 -Dnbprofiler.agentid=468771422"
Setting JAVA property to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: "D:\WildFlyTC-8585"

  JAVA: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java"

  JAVA_OPTS: "-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server -server -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost,127.0.0.1,ComputerName -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -agentpath:D:\NetBeans8.0.2\profiler\lib\deployed\jdk16\windows-amd64\profilerinterface.dll=D:\NetBeans8.0.2\profiler\lib,5140 -Dnbprofiler.agentid=468771422"

===============================================================================

Profiler Agent: Waiting for connection on port 5140 (Protocol version: 15)
Profiler Agent: Established connection with the tool
Profiler Agent: Local accelerated session
WARNING: Failed to load the specified log manager class org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/netbeans/lib/profiler/server/ProfilerRuntimeObjLiveness
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.<clinit>(WildFlySecurityManager.java:75)
    at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:320)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:464)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server.ProfilerRuntimeObjLiveness from [Module "org.wildfly.security.manager:main" from local module loader @6df2af02 (finder: local module finder @4c030fe1 (roots: D:\WildFlyTC-8585\modules,D:\WildFlyTC-8585\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134)
    ... 8 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/netbeans/lib/profiler/server/ProfilerRuntimeObjLiveness
    at org.jboss.as.server.SystemExiter.getExiter(SystemExiter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.as.server.SystemExiter.exit(SystemExiter.java:41)
    at org.jboss.as.server.Main.abort(Main.java:113)
    at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:320)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:464)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server.ProfilerRuntimeObjLiveness from [Module "org.jboss.as.server:main" from local module loader @6df2af02 (finder: local module finder @4c030fe1 (roots: D:\WildFlyTC-8585\modules,D:\WildFlyTC-8585\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134)
    ... 10 more
Profiler Agent: Connection with agent closed
Profiler Agent: Connection with agent closed
Profiler Agent: Initializing...
Profiler Agent: Options: >D:\NetBeans8.0.2\profiler\lib,5140<
Profiler Agent: Initialized successfully
Profiler Agent: Redefining 100 classes at idx 0, out of total 500 
Profiler Agent: Redefining 100 classes at idx 100, out of total 500 
Profiler Agent: Redefining 100 classes at idx 200, out of total 500 
Profiler Agent: Redefining 100 classes at idx 300, out of total 500 
Profiler Agent: Redefining 100 classes at idx 400, out of total 500 
Press any key to continue . . .
```

What can I do to fix that?